# Are there any rules and limits about profile pictures?

Tags: discussion, offensive, profile-picture

The profile picture of this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466624/mohammed-misto) shows young people with weapons. Is this an appropriate profile picture? What constitutes an offensive profile picture?

Comment: MSE post on the subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208551/offensive-profiles-where-to-draw-the-line

Comment: Are you asking about appropriate or allowed? inb4 everybody is offended by something.

Comment: The question is also what do do in such a case ?

Comment: What about nothing and stop moral policing?

Comment: It could be an answer.

Comment: @rene as MSE post suggest I will flag it as other

Comment: @AndréDaniel: That they aren't naked?

Comment: It is a very popular sport in the USA.  In the states I've lived in, hunting is common and children around the age of 12 attend a gun-safety course to keep them out of trouble.  There *might* be something more sinister about that avatar, but who could possibly tell from the grainy appearance?

Comment: I really don't see what's offensive in a picture of people holding weapons. And the picture is too small to even tell that they're young or not or if there's something more offensive on it. And what if they're just holding airsoft replicas ?

Comment: Te fact that something is common in a particular country (the US in this case) does not make it unoffensive by definition. I know some people consider guns innocuous but others don't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Judging by the fatigues, the image in question could vary easily be of two young military service men...

In many countries people can join, or be drafted into, the military as young as 18 and it isn't that uncommon for them to take these kinds of pictures. A few of my friends in the service would try to snap pictures whenever they qualified to use a new "cool gun" to show to people back home.

That said the image in question doesn't appear  malicious, threatening, pornographic or politically inciting so... Leave it alone.

---

If a profile picture is malicious, threatening, pornographic or politically inciting you can bring it to a moderators attention by adding a custom flag to one of the users posts explaining what you think the problem is.

---

I just looked at the picture again under magnification and I'm pretty sure that those "weapons" are paint ball guns...

[image]

If I'm not mistaken the large vessel on top of the gun is a hopper where one would load paint balls. Also it looks like the guy on the right has a typical paint ball protective mask pulled up on top of his head.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I was surprised by the uniforms. Anyway some comments and your answer mainly says there is some rules that are respected in this case.